# Can you use SVMs with strongly biased sample sizes?

Tags: classification, svm, unbalanced-classes

I want to use linear SVMs to classify two groups of objects based on ten features. However, I have a strong imbalance in group sizes with one group having a bit more than 90% of the cases. I have roughly 150.000 objects.

Is there a way to use classification and especially linear SVM classification with a bias that big? Or would you advise to use a different technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't definitely say about your data.

But recently I have had a similar dataset, almost 88% belong to one group. Linear SVM did okayish with the AUC score being 0.74 but the result was significantly improved by Random Forest. Later, I proceed with Random Forest.

Note: If you decide to go with Random Forest or any other non-parametric method eventually, be cautious about the overfit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you may need to have a different margin penalty for patterns of each class.  There have been a fair few papers on this, this is mine:

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Manipulation of prior probabilities in support vector classification, In Proceedings of the IEEE/INNS International Joint Conference on Neural Networks (IJCNN-2001), pp. 2433-2438, Washington, D.C., U.S.A., July 15-19 2001. ([pdf](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/publications/pdf/ijcnn2001.pdf))

It is important to remember though that if you use assymetric margin penalties (or equivalently resample or reweight the data based on class), it will probably over-predict the minority class in operational use, see my answer to this related question [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93730/doesnt-over-undersampling-an-imbalanced-dataset-cause-issues/93853#93853).

However, if you have a large class imbalance, the I would recommend regularised logistic regression instead.  This is because in class imbalance problems it often comes down to a matter of whether false-positive or false-negative costs are different (which is what motivates differential margin penalties), and the SVM aims to construct a hard decision boundary and doesn't care how well it models the data distribution away from the boundary.  This means you need to sort out the misclassification cost ratio *before* you fit the model.  Regularised logistic regression on the other hand aims to estimate the probabilities of class membership, which means you can accommodate different misclassification costs *after* fitting the model, which is usually easier and more flexible as sometimes you don't know the costs a-priori or they are variable.